# Not able to display the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my code in render method, I'm trying to access the value `arr[1].Title` but getting the following error.

```
public render(){
   var arr;
   return (
      {
      Array.apply(null, {length:this.state.length}).map((value, i) => {i*=6; return( <div> {
         arr = this.cardarrange(this.props.pdata[i], this.props.pdata[i+1], this.props.pdata[i+2])
      }
      {
         console.log(Object.keys(arr))
      }
      {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(arr[1].Title))
      }
      <h1>{JSON.stringify(arr[1].Title)}</h1>
   )

}<div>
 }
```

What is the reason for this

error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {_query, _options, _url, _parentUrl, _useCaching, _cachingOptions,
>   _cloneParentWasCaching, _cloneParentCacheOptions, _requestPipeline, _batch, _batchDependency, _forceCaching, delete, odata.metadata, odata.type, odata.id, odata.etag, odata.editLink,
>   FileSystemObjectType, Id, ServerRedirectedEmbedUri,
>   ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl, ContentTypeId, ComplianceAssetId, WikiField,
>   Title, CanvasContent1, BannerImageUrl, Description, PromotedState,
>   FirstPublishedDate, LayoutWebpartsContent, OData__AuthorBylineId,
>   _AuthorBylineStringId, OData__TopicHeader, OData__SPSitePageFlags, OData__OriginalSourceUrl, OData__OriginalSourceSiteId,
>   OData__OriginalSourceWebId, OData__OriginalSourceListId,
>   OData__OriginalSourceItemId, Kind, News_x0020_Categories,
>   Read_x0020_times, Video_x0020_URL, Division, Function, Cluster, MCO,
>   workplace, Card_x0020_Type, NewsSource, Enable_x0020_Share, ID,
>   Created, AuthorId, Modified, EditorId, OData__CopySource,
>   CheckoutUserId, OData__UIVersionString, GUID, LikeCount, CommentCount,
>   FileRef}).

Comment: Move your logic outside of return

Answer (score 0):

You should only have JSX (pseudo-HTML) after the `return` statement, move the rest of your code to before the `return`:

```
public render(){
   var arr = this.cardarrange(this.props.pdata[i], this.props.pdata[i+1], this.props.pdata[i+2]);
   console.log(Object.keys(arr));
   console.log(JSON.stringify(arr[1].Title));

   return (
      <h1>{JSON.stringify(arr[1].Title)}</h1>
   )
}
```

Furthermore it probably makes no sense to output stringified data for the `<h1>`, this will probably be what you need to use:

```
   return (
      <h1>{arr[1].Title}</h1>
   )
```

Comment: this.props.pdata is an array i'm mapping that one, I want to pass the first three values to a function and that function will return an array . And I want to display that array

Comment: Please elaborate on that; preferrably by [editing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59678990/edit). If it is always the first three items, use this: `this.props.pdata[0], this.props.pdata[1], this.props.pdata[2]`.

Comment: I have changed  please check

Comment: I'm sorry but the change makes little sense to me. You are assigning to `arr` inside the `.map()` function body, each time overwriting the previous assignment, and the result of `.map()` itself is never used. All that is mixed with an attempt at using JSX but that is incomplete (no closing tag). The code will probably not even compile as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Your `render` should return a valid value to display, not calculation or `console.log` constructions. But you can do any transformation before like the following

```html
public render(){
   var arr = this.cardarrange(this.props.pdata[i], this.props.pdata[i+1], this.props.pdata[i+2];
   console.log(Object.keys(arr))
   console.log(JSON.stringify(arr[1].Title))

   return (
      <h1>{JSON.stringify(arr[1].Title)}</h1>
   )
}
```

Comment: this.props.pdata is an array i'm mapping that one, I want to pass the first three values to a function and that function will return an array . And I want to display that array

Answer (score 0):

```
public render() {
let arr = this.cardarrange(propsData[i],propsData[i+1],propsData[i+2]); //returns array to display in h1
arr = JSON.stringfiy(arr);
return (
  <h1>{arr}</h1>
);
}
```

or try this to display each value of array

```
public render() {
let arr = this.cardarrange(propsData[i],propsData[i+1],propsData[i+2]); 
return arr.map(val => {
  return ( <h1>{val} </h1> );
});
}
```

Comment: this.props.pdata is an array i'm mapping that one, I want to pass the first three values to a function and that function will return an array . And I want to display that array

Comment: ok let me edit the code, function cardarrange is return array you want to display right?

Comment: try this one, and tell me does it fixes your issue.